# How to add new row to a sharepoint list in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, web-services, sharepoint, nsurlconnection

I tried using updatelistitems web service of the sharepoint. but could not find how to give the input data in the xml format along with the soap request.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since it's an integration you are doing I'd recommend using an ADO.NET adapter for SharePoint and connect through a WCF service (soap/wsdl). It will save you a lot of time and if done correctly your integration wont be proprietary.

Check this ready-made wcf service, http://www.bendsoft.com/downloads/camelot-wcf-service/, installation instructions here http://blog.bendsoft.com/category/integrations/wcf-services/.

It's open source but ships with support for the Camelot XML format, which bundles the schema along with the content if you query for data, check the example schema here http://www.bendsoft.com/downloads/sharepoint-web-parts/xml-pusher/.

To insert data into SharePoint with the WCF service you can simply do something like this

```
$SharePointNonQuery = new SharePointNonQuery(array(
    'sql' => "INSERT INTO contactform (title,email,company,message) VALUES ('John Doe','john.doe@example.com','Johns Company','A test message!')",
    'method' => 'ExecuteNonQuery',
    'connString' => 'sharepoint_connection',
    'sharedKey' => constant("WSDL_SHARED_KEY")
));
```

The example is obviously made in PHP ( http://blog.bendsoft.com/2011/04/camelot-php-tools-1-1-for-sharepoint-released/ ) but it's equally easy to create a class in Objective-C and send your command as SQL via SOAP and execute the SQL command in the WCF service.

Hope this helps!

**----------- Edits below this line -----------**

Querying the suggested WCF service from Objective-C would result in something like this

```
WSMethodInvocationRef soapReq = createSOAPRequest(url, method, namespace, params, paramOrder, reqHeaders);
```

The Url is the location of the wcf service, ie. http://yourserver.com/wcf/camelot.wcf

The method is the method IN the wcf service you want to use. The Camelot WCF service have a few default methods. Suitable in this scenario would be the ExecuteNonQuery method which takes the following arguments; sql, connString and sharedKey.

```
bool ExecuteNonQuery(string sql, string connString, string sharedKey);
```

The params is the arguments listed above, they should be sent as an associative array (NSDictionary I assume).

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"INSERT INTO YourList (title,email,company,message) VALUES ('John Doe','john.doe@example.com','Johns Company','A test message!')", @"sql", 
    @"connString", @"SharePointConnectionString", 
    @"sharedKey", @"YourPreferredKey", 
    nil];
```

The ExecuteNonQuery is a bool method it will return true or false to the soapReq method in the Objective-C application.

Comment: The thing is i want it completely in objective-c. the soap request format for uploading data in sharepoint list. How to insert this sql query in the soap request in objective c??

Comment: Updated my answer a bit with an explanatory how to use the WCF service with Objective-C. You can chat with the SharePoint Web Services directly without using a proxy like the Camelot WCF service, but you will end up writing proprietary integrations that consumes massive amounts of time, not to mention the maintenance of the code if something changes in the SharePoint installation. With the suggested solution above you simple have to change the SQL Query if something changes. Anyway, check this url for more information about Objective-C and Soap http://bit.ly/lZOjzG